# Is live reloading ever preferrable to hot reloading?

Tags: react-native, hot-module-replacement

When creating an app with `react-native init` I have hot reloading and live reloading automatically configured and can enable them from the developer tools. I understand that Live Reload will reload an app, whereas Hot Reload will just reload changed files and maintain your current state in the development environment.

From these descriptions I've read it sounds like Hot Reloading is always preferable to Live Reloading and I should never even bother to enable Live Reload. I'm curious to know if there is any time where Live Reload is more advantageous? Or is it just some sort of built in fallback in case Hot Reload won't work with your other dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

When it's about UI things hot reload looks enough. There some UI change that breaks hot reload. For example removing `flex:1` for some components in android. I think for developing UI part it's okay to just use the hot reload. But when the logic comes, it's a different story. For example testing your fetch which lives is in the `componentDidMount`. You have to reload the app. Or you are debugging the app. Making some changes want to see the changes in the debugger.